Is it better to use a callback or hoist state if values from one composable are needed in another composable e.g. parent?
When one needs a state from e.g. a child composable, one can use state hoisting as well as callbacks for that. Is there any best practice or recommendation when to use which of them? Do I gain any advantage of maybe using state as that is coming directly with Compose?
@Composable
fun MyParent() {
    // A) is better to use this
    val state = remember {
        mutableIntStateOf(0)
    }
    // imagine some code here using the value from state
    
    MyComponent(state = state)
    
    // B) or is it better to use
    val callback : (Int) -> Unit = {
        // imagine some code here using the value
    }
    
    MyComponent(onUpdate = callback)
}

@Composable
fun MyComponent(
    state: MutableIntState
) {
    state.intValue = 10
}

@Composable
fun MyComponent(
    onUpdate: (Int) -> Unit
) {
    onUpdate(10)
}


In terms of separation and child composable not knowing what is happening lambda callback is preferable but if changed value used in more composable or some components should be recomposed  , state hoisting would be more efficient.

Both callback and state hoisting are valid approaches in Jetpack Compose for sharing data between composables. The choice between them often depends on the specific use case and preferences, but there are some considerations that might help you decide which approach to use.
State Hoisting:
State hoisting involves lifting the state to a higher-level composable that both the parent and child composables have access to. This approach is suitable when the parent needs to not only pass data to the child but also react to changes in that data.
State hoisting is more suitable when the state needs to be shared among multiple composables or when the state's changes affect the parent composable's behavior or UI.
Callback:
Using a callback involves passing a function from the parent to the child composable, allowing the child to communicate back with the parent by invoking this function with relevant data. This approach is useful when the child needs to communicate specific events or changes back to the parent.
Callbacks are often preferred when the interaction between the parent and child composables is more event-driven or when the child's changes do not directly affect the parent's state.

Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?
